# event on click not working in echo php

Tags: javascript, php

How to echo in php?

```
<div class="city" onclick="openCity(event,'London')">
```

I am try write sintax :

```
echo '  <  div class="  city " onclick=" openCity(event,'London') " > ';
```

But event onclick not working

Comment: That's too little info, show some code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with your quotes. You must escape the ones that suround your "London" arguement. Try this instead:

```
echo ' < div class=" city " onclick=" openCity(event,\'London\') " > ';
```

Comment: Thank you very much I try and succeed

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad it worked for you! If you could, please select my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You might getting javascript syntax error due to single quote. Please you started echo with single quote. So need to handle inner single quotes. You can handle it in two ways

```
echo '<div class=" city " onclick="openCity(event,\'London\') ">';
```

or

```
echo "< div class=\" city\" onclick=\" openCity(event,'London');\" >";
```